# Angular 2 and calendar script

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing small website using Angular 2 and I would like to implement simple calendar inside one component. Nothing big with schedules, just small calendar window with higlighted current day.
I have found some nice js script for that but later I have discovered that I cannot use  inside component in Angular2.
Is there any other way I can do this or maybe some other library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but Angular Material includes a good Angular 2 ready calendar/datepicker.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

Full Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/4SIRfrDOubZxuTcvxiCP

Docs: https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker

Comment: I dont think he is trying to implement a calendar picker

Comment: This is nice but not exactly what I am looking for. I need just small calendar window that is always visible on site (the view like when you press on calendar button from your example).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. There are a ton of JQuery modules that I think are more what you are looking for (http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Basic-Lightweight-jQuery-Calendar-Plugin-Yacal.html), so if you don't mind including JQuery you could go that route.